# El texto de la página de error aparece en inglés

Tags: bug, traducciones, stackexchange

Hace un rato Stack Overflow en español estaba caído y la pantalla que aparecía estaba en inglés:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seguido de una serie de imágenes en inglés (aprieta para verlas enteras):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código fuente es:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>We are Offline</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        iframe { border: 0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" id="pageFrame"></iframe>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 300000);
        var hostName = window.location.hostname;
        var directory = '';
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/error-director.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (top == self && directory) {
            document.getElementById('pageFrame').src = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/' + directory + '/app_offline.htm';
        } else {
            // if we get here, that means even the offline pages on sstatic are offline
            document.getElementById('pageFrame').style.height = "0px";
            document.write("<h2>Stack Exchange is currently offline, we'll be back shortly!<\/h2>");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Donde la imagen en sí se carga de `'https://cdn.sstatic.net/' + directory + '/app_offline.htm';`. Por lo que parece, usamos exactamente la misma que Stack Overflow en inglés. ¿No sería más correcto que apareciera una específica en castellano?

Mi navegador está configurado en inglés.

Comment: yo vi el texto en español :$

Comment: @JackNavaRow curioso. Intenté navegar por`'https://cdn.sstatic.net/' + directory + '/app_offline.htm` pero no fui capaz de hallar ninguna de las páginas estáticas. El fichero https://cdn.sstatic.net/error-director.js da algunas pistas pero no cononzco lo suficiente como para entender la lógica.

Comment: tengo la foto de la caida del sitio esta vez, y estaba en español, podemos cerrar esta pregunta o respondo con la imagen?

Comment: @JackNavaRow dale, sí! Sería un caso de [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: ¿De verdad esta pregunta tiene 3 votos de cierre por _Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre Stack Overflow o el software que hace que la red Stack Exchange funcione, dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda_? Es coña, ¿no?

Comment: fedorqui tal vez me equivoque :(